# How to create Sequencing in SQL when date are used as reference (Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I create sequencing number  in this table in SQL(oracle)?

(TABLE NAME: PAYXX)

```
ID   Sequence Pay Date      Pay Coverage    Pay Coverage End
                            Start   
ID101         7/25/2021     3/22/2021       6/27/2021
ID101         3/21/2021     3/8/2021        3/21/2021
ID101         5/2/2021      12/28/2020      3/21/2021
ID102         2/21/2021     2/8/2021        2/21/2021
ID102         3/7/2021      2/22/2021       3/7/2021
ID102         4/4/2021      3/22/2021       4/4/2021
ID103         7/25/2021     3/22/2021       6/27/2021
ID103         2/7/2021      1/25/2021       2/7/2021
ID103         2/21/2021     2/8/2021        2/21/2021
ID103         3/7/2021      2/22/2021       3/7/2021
ID103         3/7/2021      9/21/2020       12/27/2020
ID103         3/21/2021     3/8/2021        3/21/2021
```

It should look like this

```
ID   Sequence Pay Date      Pay Coverage    Pay Coverage End
                            Start   
ID101   3     7/25/2021     3/22/2021       6/27/2021
ID101   1     3/21/2021     3/8/2021        3/21/2021
ID101   2     5/2/2021      12/28/2020      3/21/2021
ID102   1     2/21/2021     2/8/2021        2/21/2021
ID102   2     3/7/2021      2/22/2021       3/7/2021
ID102   3     4/4/2021      3/22/2021       4/4/2021
ID103   5     7/25/2021     3/22/2021       6/27/2021
ID103   1     2/7/2021      1/25/2021       2/7/2021
ID103   2     2/21/2021     2/8/2021        2/21/2021
ID103   3     3/7/2021      2/22/2021       3/7/2021
ID103   3     3/7/2021      9/21/2020       12/27/2020
ID103   4     3/21/2021     3/8/2021        3/21/2021
```

Comment: Which date column(s) are being used to determine the sequencing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen looks like `Pay Date` since the sequence has a repeated "3" for ID103

Answer (score 1):

You want `DENSE_RANK` here.  Assuming that the pay date be the column which determines the ranking within each `ID` group:

```sql
SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY pay_date) seq
FROM yourTable t
ORDER BY ID, pay_date;
```